# Online file viewer and editor like Google Docs

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to edit text/pdf/excel files on the website itself and want to save it back to the server via the website. I'm looking for an editor plugin similar to Google Docs, but for Joomla.

Is there any viewer/editor api available?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you have a look at hotscripts.com

i saw couple of scripts that might fit your description. But never in one single script for that i think you will need to write it by yourself

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't get any proper reference at hotscripts...It would be nice if you refer any pdf/word editor